# Random word problem for unknown groups.

Tags: probability, group-theory

Suppose that I pick a group $G$ from a distribution $X$, unknown to you, and I give you a generating set $|S|$ for $G$, and a word $x$ in $S$ and their formal inverses, and a set $T$ of sentences of the form $y = 1$ or $y \ne 1$ which are true in $G$ but do not necessarily give a presentation of $G$ (for instance, we can have something like $G= \langle \{r, f\} \mid r^n = 1, f^2 = 1, (fr)^2 = 1>\rangle = D_n$, and $T = \{r^{5n}f^{-3} \ne 1 \}$). For simplicity, the distribution over words is $P(w) = (2|S|)^{-l(w)}$ where $l(w)$ is the length of $w$.

Your goal is to guess whether $w=1$, so I want to figure out what prior to put over words. This will by highly dependent on $X$ if $X$ is known.

My particular problem is, what if it is known that $X$ is a uniform distribution over (isomorphism classes) groups of cardinality $n$, how does this affect the probability of short words equaling the identity? It seems like for sufficiently long words, we should have $P(w = 1) = 1/n$, because we are essentially picking a uniformly random element from $G$. However, it seems like if $n$ is large, and $|S|$ is small, then shorter words are less likely to be true, because there needs to be more higher order elements to "fill out" the group.

Questions

1. Is my intuition true? How do I show this?
2. Is there any literature on this, or similar problems?

Comment: Are you considering only finite groups?

Comment: In the general problem, no, it depends on the distribution $X$. In the specific problem, yes, $X$ is a uniform distribution over isomorphism classes of groups of some particular finite cardinality.